# Monstrous Morphemes

Tags: crossword-clues, seasonal

Below are thirteen clues that describe paired words. The first word in each pair is an atrocious attribute. The second word is a fearful figure. The words in the pair share a sort-of stem (or simply a set) of consecutive letters.

**Example:** 
*Shopworn shrieker states stale stories* = *banal  banshee*

> 1. Building bedizenment battling bad breath
> 2. Bustling bones belike buzzing bumblebee
> 3. Candid composite corpse constructor
> 4. Clever cackler who can conjure with a cauldron
> 5. Counterfeit kidnapper
> 6. Flirty fluid fleecer
> 7. Form fitting fabric on feral full-moon fancier
> 8. Halfling hater who is a philharmonic harpist
> 9. Prejudiced and with pileous, prodigious pedes
> 10. Reserved and preserved
> 11. Serpent-stranded sister swallowing excessively
> 12. Warmongering wishmaker with wispless warmth
> 13. Wild haunter in the White House

Comment: Can the consecutive letters be anywhere in the words? Or only the beginning

Comment: Is there a minimum number of letters in the stem?

Comment: Decorate and halitosis both share the letter "a", but I assume is not the answer you're looking for.

Comment: @DrXorile I opted to not reveal these hints, but since you've asked: this puzzle has the stems at the beginning, and they're at least 3 letters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some guesses (and a lot of help from the commentators!):

1. Building bedizenment battling bad breath

   > garlic-breathed gargoyle
   >  OP alternative: gargling gargoyle
2. Bustling bones belike buzzing bumblebee

   > skedaddling skeleton
   >  OP alternative: skeltering skeleton
3. Candid composite corpse constructor

   > frank Frankenstein
4. Clever cackler who can conjure with a cauldron

   > witty witch
5. Counterfeit kidnapper

   > bogus bogeyman
6. Flirty fluid fleecer

   > vampish vampire
7. Form fitting fabric on feral full-moon fancier

   > Lycra-wearing lycanthrope
8. Halfling hater who is a philharmonic harpist

   > orchestral orc
9. Prejudiced and with pileous, prodigious pedes

   > bigoted Bigfoot
10. Reserved and preserved

    > mum mummy
11. Serpent-stranded sister swallowing excessively

    > gorging Gorgon
12. Warmongering wishmaker with wispless warmth

    > genocidal genie
    >  OP alternative: jingoistic jinn
13. Wild haunter in the White House

    > political poltergeist

Comment: Didn't expect such a fitting equivalent, so I'll just reveal that I intended #12 to be “jingoistic jinn". Thanks, Community!

Comment: Jingoistic doesn't connote warmongering for me. But great puzzle. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: Thanks again for your efforts, Dr! I've edited your answer to include my alternative answers in case people were wondering.

Answer (score 4):

1 - Building bedizenment (ornament or dressing, according to google) battling bad breath

> Garlicy gargoyle (with thanks to Fillet)

5 - Counterfeit kidnapper

> Bogus Bogeyman

7 - Form fitting fabric on feral full-moon fancier

> Lycra-clad Lycanthrope

8 - Halfling hater who is a philharmonic harpist

> Orchestral Orc

11 - Serpent-stranded sister swallowing excessively

> <strike>Guzzling</strike> Gorging Gorgon

12 - Warmongering wishmaker with wispless warmth (borrowing from APrough's comment)

> Genocidal Genie

Comment: Since at least the first 3 letters of each word pair are the same (per OP), might I suggest Gorging Gorgon for #11.

Comment: Indeed you might!

Comment: All 3 are correct, including the adjective forms I was intending :)...except #7 is special for obvious reasons

Comment: I've added '-clad' to #7 - hopefully that flows a little better